# Delay no scroll impende o clique em um componente usando o selenium no Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Tenho alguns componentes na minha tela em uma section que possui um scroll.

Quando tento realizar um click em um componente onde é necessário o uso do scroll para encontrar o componente. Porém aparentemente o scroll tem um delay e quando o Selenium tenta fazer o click o meu componente ainda não está "visível".
Isso gera o seguinte erro:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not
>   clickable at point

Atualmente eu estou fazendo o Scrolling e Click da seguinte maneira:

```
public void scrollAndClick(WebElement webElement) {
        Actions action = new Actions(webDriver);
        action.moveToElement(webElement);
        action.perform();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webElement));
        webElement.click();
}
```

Também tentei desabilitar scroll-smooth do Chrome através do comando `--disable-smooth-scrolling` porém esse comando não tem efeito nenhum, pesquisando encontrei alguma issues abertas pra esse caso.

Eu poderia colocar um `Thread.sleep` antes do clique, porém não ficaria legal.

Alguém tem alguma outra sugestão?

Comment: Não sei se vai te ajudar, mas é apenas uma ideia, não teria como você pegar pelo xpath item aonde vai ser clicado assim não teria a necessidade de ter o item na tela,

Comment: Entendi, mas como eu faria isso. O click seria feito por JavaScript?

Comment: tu pode usar por exemplo ` element = body.find_element_by_xpath.('xpath do elemento')` depois de encontrar ele `elemento.click();` caso fique estranho eu só usei o selenium em python mas creio que a ideia seja a mesma.

Comment: Então, isso é o que eu já faço hoje. o 'webElement' que aparece no meu código já é o xpath. :(

Comment: Ele só "aparece" para o xpath quando ele fica em tela ?

Comment: Sim. Enquanto a animação de scroll não termina, não consigo clicar no componente. Mas o mesmo já existe no DOM

Comment: Você consegue mover a pagina com as teclas poderia fazer o que enviar um comando de teclado para descer a tela criar um sleep e depois da continuidade ao script, é apena uma ideia.

Comment: Então, acho que não seria legal usar um sleep. Mas valeu pelas ideias.

Comment: quando falei sleep me referia ao método que espera até que um item apareça, tu define um tempo até que ele apareça.